# Insert a string before the extension in a filename

Tags: javascript, string, split

How can I insert a string before the extension in an image filename? For example, I need to convert this:

```
../Course/Assess/Responsive_Course_1_1.png
```

to this:

```
../Course/Assess/Responsive_Course_1_1_large.png
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If we assume that an extension is any series of letters, numbers, underscore or dash after the last dot in the file name, then:

```
filename = filename.replace(/(\.[\w\d_-]+)$/i, '_large$1');
```

Comment: doesn't work if filename has no extension, check my answer below for a solution that works in **all** cases

Comment: Won't work if a filename doesn't have an extension but a folder does. Any solution that doesn't involve `path.extname` is wrong.

Answer (score 30):

None of the answers works if file **doesn't have extension**.
Here's a solution that works for all cases.

```
function appendToFilename(filename, string){
    var dotIndex = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (dotIndex == -1) return filename + string;
    else return filename.substring(0, dotIndex) + string + filename.substring(dotIndex);
}
```

Comment: Isn't the question is about appending prior to extension? If there is no file extension concate string with filename. Life is simple no?

Comment: For `appendToFilename("filename.tar.gz", "-copy")`, this would result in `filename.tar-copy.gz`.

Comment: @Kamran No, life is not simple. As a developer once said: Making the program do what it must do is easy. The hard part is to make it not do what it must not do.

Answer (score 23):

Use javascript lastIndexOf, something like:

```
var s = "Courses/Assess/Responsive_Cousre_1_1.png";
var new_string = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(".")) + "_large" + s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Comment: This method is faster than the regex based one (not surprising).
For 100000000 elements: 
Regex: 41s
lastIndexOf: 15s

Comment: @AntoineBolvy Thanks for adding this information. I am curious how you tested this?

Comment: I'll be honest it's been three years, and I don't remember. Just a basic loop I guess.

Comment: Won't work if a filename doesn't have an extension but a folder does. Any solution that doesn't involve `path.extname` is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

```
var s = '../Course/Assess/Responsive_Course_1_1.png'
s.replace(/\.png$/, '_large.png');
```

This will do the job. By the way, it's night here. :)

**UPDATE:**

A more general way would be this:

```
var s = '../Course/Assess/Responsive_Course_1_1.png';
s.replace(/(\.[^\.]+)$/, '_large$1');
```

Comment: but that's what he asked for. Now, if I were you, I would've told this: _yes, he asked for only png. But he didn't say he didn't want a general solution!_. Fine, I'll update it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Either $1 match a filename with no extension or $2 match an extension.

```
filename = filename.replace(/^([^.]+)$|(\.[^.]+)$/i, '$1' + "_large" + '$2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple regex replace

`filename = filename.replace(/(\.[^.]+)$/i, '_large$1')`

Answer (score 0):

for files without extension and files includes extension. thanks @paul !

`filename = filename.replace(/^([^.]+)$|(\.[^.]+)$/i, '$1' + "-thumb" + '$2');`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure what could be the incoming file's extension then this helps:

```js
function renameFileA(imgUrl) {
  var extension = `.${imgUrl.split('.').pop()}`
  var [fileName] = imgUrl.split(extension);
  return `${fileName}_large${extension}`;
};

// this is clean but I don't understand what's going on till I do research ;)
function renameFileB(imgUrl) {
  return imgUrl.replace(/(\.[\w\d_-]+)$/i, '_large$1');
};

var valA = renameFileA('http//www.app.com/img/thumbnails/vid-th.png');
var valB = renameFileB('http//www.app.com/img/thumbnails/vid-th.jpg');

console.log('valA', valA);
console.log('valB', valB);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just in case**: Flexible to change pattern like **prefix** or **suffix**

```js
const url = 'https://example.com/path/filename.png?a&b=c'
const regex = /((?:.+\/.+)+\/)(.?.+)+\.(.+)/

const result1 = url.replace(regex,'$1prefix_$2.$3')
const result2 = url.replace(regex,'$1$2_suffix.$3')
const result3 = '../Course/Assess/Responsive_Course_1_1.png'.replace(regex,'$1$2_large.$3')
const result4 = '../path/file'.replace(/(\/)(.?.+)/,'$1$2_suffix')

console.log(result1) // https://example.com/path/prefix_filename.png?a&b=c
console.log(result2) // https://example.com/path/filename_suffix.png?a&b=c
console.log(result3) // ../Course/Assess/Responsive_Course_1_1_large.png
console.log(result4) // ../path/file_suffix
```

**Credit: Regex from:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/60538390/622813