# How can I insert text before the file extension with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, shopify

I have image URLs like this

```
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0919/5078/products/DSC_9782-processed_9bef16cb-7700-48d9-ad6d-f9a350e7f6c7.jpg?v=1579953393
```

I need to insert `_small` before the file extension in order to get that image size and it should look like this

```
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0919/5078/products/DSC_9782-processed_9bef16cb-7700-48d9-ad6d-f9a350e7f6c7_small.jpg?v=1579953393
```

(Images can have different file extensions.)

What's the best way to do this with JavaScript? Maybe Regex?

Tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802337/1419575) Regex, but it doesn't work with the `?v=1579953393` after the file extension.

Comment: One approach is to ``split`` the string using *.jpg* (Only if we are sure that every time 
 the image will be of format jpg).   `` let strArr = imgUrl.split('.jpg');`` then ``strArr[0]`` will give you end where you can add your **_small**

Comment: The right way would be to parse the whole URL and then update the file name. Then you can rebuild the URL with the updated file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to rework [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802337/1419575) to do the job. It looks like this and it works as expected.

```
image = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0919/5078/products/DSC_9782-processed_9bef16cb-7700-48d9-ad6d-f9a350e7f6c7.jpg?v=1579953393';
image = image.replace(/(\.[\w\d?=_-]+)$/i, '_small$1');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let str = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0919/5078/products/DSC_9782-processed_9bef16cb-7700-48d9-ad6d-f9a350e7f6c7.jpg?v=1579953393";
let[filename, extension] = str.split('.jpg');

let rename = filename+'_small.'+extension;

console.log('New file name',rename);
```

Hope , it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Regex:

```
((?:.+\/.+)+\/)(.?.+)+\.(.+)\?(.*)
```

```js
var url = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0919/5078/products/DSC_9782-processed_9bef16cb-7700-48d9-ad6d-f9a350e7f6c7.jpg?v=1579953393';
url = url.replace(/((?:.+\/.+)+\/)(.?.+)+\.(.+)\?(.*)/,"$1$2_small.$3?$4");
alert(url);
```

```
((?:.+\/.+)+\/) : matches text from starting to last slash (/) - protocol,host, and folders 
(.?.+)+         : filename 
\.              : Specific char . - before file extension
(.+)            : file extension
\?              : special character ? - starting of search params
(.*)            : search params
```

Then replace groups like:

```
$1$2_small.$3?$4
```

Comment: Ritesh, thanks for the input! It does get close to what I needed, but it just over-complicates the task, since there's just one variable to be changed. No need to capture different parts of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be this, where you are sure that image extension is **.jpg**. 
Then you can `split` the string.

```js
let str = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0919/5078/products/DSC_9782-processed_9bef16cb-7700-48d9-ad6d-f9a350e7f6c7.jpg?v=1579953393';

let strArr = str.split('.jpg');

console.log(strArr[0]);

let newStr = `${strArr[0]}_small`;

console.log(newStr);

let url = `${newStr}.jpg${strArr[1]}`;

console.log(url);
```

Evening using `URL` [interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. You just need to add each extension type that could be used to the `fileTypes` array.

```js
const url = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0919/5078/products/DSC_9782-processed_9bef16cb-7700-48d9-ad6d-f9a350e7f6c7.jpg?v=1579953393";

const fileTypes = ['.jpg','.png']; //add each extension that you will use here.

const urlType = fileTypes.filter(type => url.search(type)> 0)[0];

let newUrl = urlType ? url.replace(urlType,`_small${urlType}`) : null;

console.log(newUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solutions aren't always the shortest or the most elegant, however, I think they are their weight in readability.

I didn't like the extensibility or readability of the solutions above so I wrote this function:

```
append_to_file_name (file_name, str_to_append) {

    if (file_name && file_name.indexOf('.') >= 0) {

        let file_qs;
        let file_ext;
        let file_name_array = [];
        let file_q_index = file_name.indexOf('?');

        if (file_q_index >= 0) {

            file_qs = file_name.substring(file_q_index);
            file_name = file_name.substring(0, file_q_index);

        }

        file_name_array = file_name.split('.');
        file_ext = file_name_array.pop();

        file_name = (`${ file_name_array.join() }${ str_to_append }.${ file_ext }${ file_qs }`);

    }

    return file_name;

},
```